# Reference to PHP method without using a string

Tags: php, reflection, automated-refactoring

Suppose I have the following PHP code:

```
class Foo {
    function getBar() {
         return 1;
    }
}

function check( Foo $foo ) {
    if ( $foo->getBar() == 1 ) {
       // here could be more code ...
       return 'Oh no, there was an error in class' . 
              get_class( $foo ) . ', method ' .
              'getBar';
    }
}
```

The last string in `check` bothers me because if `Foo::bar` gets renamed by a refactoring tool, the error message will be wrong. Is there any way to get around this without using a string somewhere?

Comment: Not really clear what you try to achieve. If you call `getBar` - you can print `getBar`. If you refactor the class, you have to refactor your check-function.

Comment: Made the problem (method name in string that doesn't get caught by automated refactoring tool when renaming) more clear in the text.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. The same problem exists in phpunit too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use __METHOD__ to get the name of the current method.

But to get reference to other method that would allow you some kind of automatic refactoring - no, it's not possible in php.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by using method_exists()

```
class Foo {
    function getBar() {
         return 1;
    }
}

function check( Foo $foo , $method = 'getBar') {
    if (!method_exists($foo, $method) ) {
       // here could be more code ...
       return 'Oh no, there was an error in class' . 
              get_class( $foo ) . ', method ' .
              $method;
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes the error more likely to be caught in unit tests (because they will fail when `getBar` no longer exists), but does not solve the "Is there any way around this without using a string" question.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in PHP per se, but you can implement such a feature. One possible implementation would work as follows: somewhere the file path, class name, method name and some kind of a description of where and what should match what. Your new feature whenever triggered would check the given files, check whether some values changed, fix whatever needs to be fixed and log a report about the task. It would not be simple to implement something like this, but, important to note is that there is a solution.